# Trouble creating a long

Tags: java, long-integer

`long timeStamp = 1312561140157;`
gives me an error saying that the litter is too large of type int

I know I can set a long to `System.currentTimeMillis()` and this number `i` used is an output from the `currentTimeMillis()`.

Anyone know how to make a literal work when it is this big?

Comment: Did you mean to use the word 'litter'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this `long timeStamp = 1312561140157L`. Just append `L` to the end of the number.

Answer (score 2):

When you create a `long` you need put an 'L' character at the end of the number.

example:
`long timeStamp = 1312561140157L;`

You can use lowercase or uppercase 'L', but generally you should use uppercase because `l` can be easily confused with `1`